# (check-sat) then (check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)

Tags: z3, smt

**What I want to do:** I would like to call `(check-sat)`, and then if the result is `unknown`, call `(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)`.

**Why do I want to do this?:** For my application the Z3 default tactics applied with `(check-sat)` are superior to anything I have devised using `(check-sat-using)`.  However, there are a few situations where `(check-sat)` returns `unknown`, but  `(check-sat-using ...)` with judiciously chosen tactics finds a result.  Here is an example:

```
(declare-fun x () Real)
(declare-fun y () Real)
(declare-fun z () Real)

(declare-fun i () Int)
(declare-fun j () Int)
(declare-fun k () Int)

(assert (= z (* x y)))
(assert (= k (* i j)))
(assert (< k z))

; This returns unknown
(check-sat)

; This gives a solution
(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)
(get-value (x y z i j k))
```

**What have I tried?:** The closest I've come in a single SMT file is`(check-sat-using (or-else smt qfnra-nlsat)).` Unfortunately `(check-sat-using smt)` does not perform as well as `(check-sat)` for my purposes, so this is not an option.

Comment: Can't you simply read the result of `(check-sat)` and then emit a `(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)` if the previous result was `unknown`? I use Z3, via stdio, like this all the time.

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff If I were using Z3 in interactive mode then I could do this, yes. The current process I am using is to write a complete .smt2 file, call Z3 with my .smt2 file as input, and then read the result. This has some advantages over having my software use Z3 interactively or via a more sophisticated API. What you suggest isn't a bad idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible directly using `(check-sat)`, but the `default` tactic used by `(check-sat)` was exposed following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443308/check-sat-using-default-or-similar/37443868#37443868).  So, in the current master branch of Z3, it's possible to write:

```
(check-sat-using (or-else default qfnra-nlsat))
```

This feature should be available with Z3 4.4.2 and greater.