# (check-sat-using default) or similar?

Tags: z3

When Z3 is run with no logic specified, and `(check-sat)` is issued, the logic in [default_tactic.cpp](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/tactic/portfolio/default_tactic.cpp) is used to conditionally invoke the "best" solver.  I would like to access this default tactic from the SMT-LIB 2 interface.

I tried translating the logic from default_tactic.cpp into SMT-LIB, and I came up with this:

```
(check-sat-using (and-then simplify
    (cond is-qfbv qfbv
    (cond is-qflia qflia
    (cond is-qflra qflra
    (cond is-qfnra qfnra
    (cond is-qfnia qfnia
    (cond is-nra nra
    (cond is-lira lira
    (cond is-qffpabv qffpa
    smt))))))))))
```

This "almost" works, in that, if you delete the lines with `nra`, `lira`, and `qffpa`, then Z3 will execute this without issue.  It seems that those three tactics are not exposed with the SMT-LIB 2 interface of Z3 4.4.1.  Another problem with this, though, is that if the default tactic is updated in a future revision of Z3, then any hard-coded strategy like what I wrote above would not be updated.

What I would really like to do is issue a command like `(check-sat-using default)`, or something similar, and get the same result as as obtained with `(check-sat)`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you refer to is very old. Z3 has since moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/) and the latest version of default_tactic.cpp is [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/portfolio/default_tactic.cpp).

The default tactic for QF_FP is now called `qffp`, the `lira` tactic has since been exported as well and I just exported `nra` as well (as of [this commit](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/ce69072305c37c6685c538794c187cf6ebc2385f)).

---

**Edit:** As of [this commit](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/725b1c56e572fb4c63f78680b9f89da7511b0a23), the `default` tactic has also been exported, so it's now possible to write `(check-sat-using default)` as requested.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I clone and build z3 master, and amend what I wrote above to match the most recent version of `default_tactic.cpp`, then I get a strategy using `check-sat-using` that matches the behavior of `check-sat`.

Comment: This still has the problem that if `default_tactic.cpp` is updated, then the custom `(check-sat-using ...` command will not benefit from the update. Instead, I tried exporting the default tactic by adding a line to `default_tactic.h` similar to the one you added to `nra_tactic.h`, and this worked great! If I commit it and make a pull request on GitHub, would you consider merging it into master?

Comment: Sure, we'll definitely consider it. It may be a bit redundant as (check-sat) does the same as (apply default), but I suppose you have some use-case that combines the default tactic with others?

Comment: OK, great. Yes, the idea is to allow users to build off the default tactic.  Thanks for considering it.